# Bruteforcing the discrete logarithm with a decomposable prime modulus

Tags: discrete-logarithm

I came across an interesting challenge recently. I need to find x such as :
$s=n^x \mod m$

We suppose we have $s, n$ and $m$. The modulus $m$ is prime and $n$ is a primitive root modulo $m$.

The interesting property is that $m$ can be written as $m=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$ where $a,b,c,d$ are integers.

Given the decomposition of $m$ above, is there a way to bruteforce or simply solve for $x$ ?

Comment: That's not an interesting property, all numbers can be written in that way and it's quite easy to find such a representation. See [Lagrange's four square theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem).

Comment: You are right, I was mislead ... The solution was Pohling Hellman !